# MDM Push Text Message on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

I want to implement Push text message service inside the iOS MDM server, I don't want to store message, I want to show it on the screen only. Can anyone tell me how to implement this or provide the some references or tutorials to implement this functionality. I am not getting any clue. Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

a) It has nothing to do with MDM.

b) It's called [Push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) which is standalone functionality and can be used with or without MDM.

Comment: Do I need to create an app for that or we can sent the push notification without that too ??? I have the device token and push magic of the device.

Comment: Yes. You need to have an app. Push notification is sent to the app which is registered for receiving push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You will find [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2) a nice Tutorial of Push Chat using [push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

URL: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2

if you are not aware of [push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html), then use [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) to get started.

Comment: Do I need to create an app for that or we can sent the push notification without that too ??? I have the device token and push magic of the device.

Comment: Yes, you can create an app to send/receive push messages. Also you can send message from a browser to device too.